# Get sliding window mean with no overlap

Tags: python, pandas, sliding-window

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id_val' : [1,2,3,4,5] , 'c1': [1.0 , 2.0, 3.0,4.0,5.0]})
```

[image]

I'm attempting to return mean of sliding window of every 2 values of row c1 with no overlap:

mean of `[1,2] , [3,4] , [5]` = `[1.5 , 3.5, 5 ]`

```
df.rolling(2)['c1'].mean()[1::2]
```

returns:

[image]

Which I think translates to take a rolling window of size 2, calculate mean of 'c1', `[1::2]` means start at second row and return every second row. Is this correct ?

In order to return [5] which is mean of final row I could return last value of c1 for the dataframe but this seems clunky, is there a cleaner method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this way:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['c1'],[0,2,4,6]))['c1'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Results in :

```
0    1.5
1    3.5
2    5.0
Name: c1, dtype: float64
```